# Как убрать эффект скольжения при повороте камерой в Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity3d

при повороте по оси x возникает эффект скольжения(то есть камера останавливается не сразу как я отпустил мышь),после добавления следующей строки(она мне нужна чтобы игрок шел по направлению камеры):

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles.x,   camera.transform.eulerAngles.y, transform.eulerAngles.z);
```

как убрать скольжение? если кому-то нужен код то вот(надеюсь на вашу помощь):

```
void Update()
  {
   //переменные
   public float sensX = 7f;
   public float sensY = 2f;
   public float minY = -30f;
   public float maxY = 30f;
   private float x, y;
   private float rotY;

   //тут начинается бойня с поворотом
   x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
   y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

   float rotX = camera.localEulerAngles.y + Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") /sensX;
   rotY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensY;
   rotY = Mathf.Clamp(rotY, minY, maxY);
   transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles.x, camera.transform.eulerAngles.y, transform.eulerAngles.z);
   camera.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotY, rotX, 0);
  }
```

Comment: А есть возможность сделать гифку с проблемой?)

Comment: не умею делать гифки) если вам не понятно я могу по другому объяснить

Comment: `Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")` будет возвращать отличные от 0 значения после резкой остановки мыши просто потому что это так работает. Надо как минимум попробовать пошаманить с `Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y")`

Comment: я поставил Raw и ничего не изменилось( но если убрать строчку, которую я добавил чтобы персонаж двигался за камерой, то этого скольжения нет

Comment: Я не вижу этой строчки, если честно.

Comment: Похоже что проблема не в этом участке или не только в этом

Comment: transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles.x, camera.transform.eulerAngles.y, transform.eulerAngles.z);
вот она,я ее еще в описание проблемы писал.